# event.id undefined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched previous questions but the answers don't seem to contribute to my problem.

```
$("button").on("click", function (event) {
  var userChosenColor = event.id;
});

console.log(userChosenColor);
```

In the code above the console log shows that the userChosenColor is not defined. I changed it to

```
event.target.id
```

(although I don't really know what is target) but I can't get the id successfully.

Comment: You need to put the `console.log()` *inside* the click handler, that being said `id` isn't a standard property of an `Event` object, so I'm not sure what you're expecting to see. Also note that `event.id` and `event.target.id` are two completely different things

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Also, this code is trying to access a global variable. The click hander has a local variable.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel there's no globals in the OPs logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

> A reference to the object that dispatched the event. It is different from `event.currentTarget` when the event handler is called during the bubbling or capturing phase of the event.

**The issue is with the [Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of the execution context of `console.log()`.**

`console.log()` is executed way before the event handler function is executed. You have to console the output inside the event handler function so that it can be executed when the event is fired.

```js
$("button").on("click", function (event) {
  var userChosenColor = event.target.id;
  console.log(userChosenColor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` isn't running inside of the click handler, but rather on page load. As such, `userChosenColor` is indeed `undefined`.

You need to move all of your logic inside the callback:

```
$("button").on("click", function (event) {
    var userChosenColor = event.target.id;
    console.log(userChosenColor);
});
```

Also notice that we have to use `event.target.id` in order to get the actual ID of the element (`event.id` isn't a standard property).

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding I added console log both inside and outside code. The outside console log executes on the page load whereas the inside console log executes when you click the button. And in terms of event.target, MDN documentation explains that `A reference to the object that dispatched the event`. In the following scenario, event target is the button element.

```js
 var userChosenColor;
$("button").on("click", function (event) {
  userChosenColor = event.target.id;
  console.log('inside', userChosenColor);
});

console.log('outside', userChosenColor);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <button id="buttonId"> Click me!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in this exam event is click. and target is that element you click it. and id is that clicked element id